# Correct primitive to start with for modified cone shape

Tags: 3d, geometry, maya, 3d-modeling

I am very new to Maya and trying to make a Nikon F camera from reference images.

I can't quite wrap my head around how I would make the shape on top of the camera because it is essentially a square cone but has some modifications to the base and front slanted side that I can't seem to achieve with a square pyramid, I believe because of the rules of quad/tri geometries

Is this possible by starting with a square cone? If so how do I apply the relevant loop cuts horizontally and vertically?
Alternatively if is best to construct with another primitive could someone please detail which one?

[image: Real subject]

[image: front_ortho]

[image: side_ortho]

Comment: I'd start with a simple triangle and just [extrude](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya-lt/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/MayaLT/files/GUID-20202ED3-5EC7-420E-860E-EC29D101A7A8-htm.html) the edges to get the required faces, but any shape can be translated to any other. It's probably more time efficient to just try your own suggestion instead of asking for the best way

Comment: You may get better answers here on a site dedicated to 3D modelling, like the [Polycount technical talk forum](https://polycount.com/categories/technical-talk). To me though, this looks like a peaked roof (triangular prism) with a couple of cut planes subtracting from it to create the slanted triangle faces in front & back.